# Is a printer's 2400 x 1200 dpi overkill for a Mac?

Tags: graphics

I'm an absolute amateur when it comes to anything IT.  I need a new printer and need help in finding the right route to take.  I used HP for years and years and, possibly irrationally, decided I needed better and more. Because I print a more than average category of invitations (friends/family parties & events), I decided to step up to a Lexmark (without advice).  It was a lemon from day on; money not well spent. I'm now looking at Xerox.  The number of choices make my head spin.  Graphics are of significant importance to me.  I'm looking at models that boast of, "Maximum True Color Print Resolution" of 2400 x 1200 dpi and 1200 x 1200 dpi. If dpi will improve the final product, is bigger necessarily better? Will there be an issue in reproducing the image sent from my Mac?

Comment: My experience with lexmarks are attrocious... Avoid

Comment: Think of a colour/graphics printer's DPI rating as a sort of proxy for its ability to accurately reproduce colours in a small area with the limited number of ink or toner colours that it has to work with (and, consequently, for its ability to suppress banding in gradients). You might not need more than, say, 300 pixels per inch for images (text will be crisper and smoother with more), but it really, really helps if those pixels are the right colour and shade.

Comment: Manufacturer's DPI specifications are (almost) meaningless in terms of real-world results. I've seen vastly superior output from a color printer that claimed a maximum of only 600 DPI, than from a cheaper one that claimed 2400 DPI. If you're serious about this, start reading up on genuine reviews and possibly obtain sample prints from a short-list of printers. Don't forget that the paper you print on may have a significant effect on output quality as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have an issue whatsoever. I believe the better question is can my "Mac" or any computer for that matter handle the file size I am trying to process. Of-course, if I understand you correctly. Unless it's a very old computer, I don't think you'll have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Xerox is very good quality when you start spending on the $800+ models on lettersize. The lowest priced ones are often the "laser" quality, a bit like the HP laser printers but still nice quality. You can order printed samples from Xerox to see with your own eyes what kind of quality you'll get. Yes the quality will increase if you take more dpi but that doesn't mean you'll need it and that resolution is in the "ideal conditions" which also means "longer to print"!

Usually what increases the cost of printer at some point is the duplex function, speed and tabloid option to save on print costs. You might want to invest on duplex if you do a lot of prints back/front. You don't really mention how many copies per month you plan to print; you can find info about the suggested Xerox model based on how many copies you can expect to handle with each of them. Some are a bit more home-version and other more office. And then the category with no price is commercial and can be a few (hundred) thousands of dollars too. Sometimes, you can rent find providers who rent these printers or the big office models.

Your Mac should be ok, just looks at the requirements on Xerox for the drivers. It's usually mentioned on their website for each printer. As ErickP mentioned, the question is more: can your mac handle the software for the design.... which frankly should be alright too because even a Mac Mini can handle very well Indesign and Photoshop projects. The version of the operating system is also important.

And if you want quality, Xerox will also be expensive. It needs some maintenance, ideally you should have a controlled environment for the humidity, the "inks" aren't cheap and it's good to make friend with a print shop to get access to good quality paper at lower cost! But if you're careful, the cost-per-page for the quality is great.